# Grouping and formatting of the list based on nth character

Tags: python, python-2.7

Input:

I have a file which has thousands of strings of same length (of 5 characters as listed above) in each newline.
Following are the properties of each string in that file,

- All the strings are of same length - 5 characters.
- The first 3 characters of the string can be called "pattern" (ie., abc, aef in the above example).
- The 4th character of each string is called "version". It can have only 3 possible values - M/L/K (as given above).
  The final character is "unique ID" of that string which is represented as number (it can have values 1,2,3).

Goal/Desired Output:

- To write out the string entries in that file into separate columns grouped by "version" (ie., L/M/K - 4th character of the string).
- Under each column the strings should be grouped based on "pattern" (ie., the first 3 characters of the string) and should be arranged in the ascending order of the "unique ID" for "pattern" (Eg. second column L in the above output).
- The common "unique ID" for a given family across multiple "version" should be arranged in a same row (eg. 1st entry in the above output). But if there is no equivalent "unique ID" for a given variant then it should marked as "-".

Eg:Input/Output

```
Input

abc**M**1
abc**L**1
aef**L**2
aef**K**3

Output

   M        L         K
  abcM1    abcL1       -
    -      aefL2       -
    -        -       aefK3
```

I was suggested to use "groupby" functions from itertools which helped in grouping the strings based on "4th" character. But I am sure not how to print these list in the desired format as given in the output above.

Comment: How can the last character be "unique ID" of a string if it can be one of 3 options, and there are thousands of strings???

Comment: What I mean is that the "pattern" can have multiple values like "abc/aef/ghi" - any combination. But given that combination, it will be either "M/L/K" version and each of these version will have only "1/2/3" as the last character as ID thereby making at entire string value unique by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the shortest answer, but it should be fairly easy to read through.

The main goal is to build a 2d map of the entries:

1. Level 1 Key in format ('abc', 1)
2. Level 2 Key one of ['M', 'L', 'K']

Here is the example, you can update `print_entries` based on your needs:

```
inputs = ['abcM1', 'abcL1', 'aefL2', 'aefK3']

def parse_inputs(inputs):
    entries = dict()    # key (abc,1), key ['M', 'L', 'K']

    for input_string in inputs:
        # parse and break down
        version = input_string[3]
        unique_id = int(input_string[4])
        key = (input_string[:3], unique_id)

        # put in ditionary
        if key not in entries:
            entries[key] = dict()
        entries[key][version] = input_string
    return entries

def print_entries(entries):
    ids = ['M', 'L', 'K']
    print '{:^6} {:^6} {:^6}'.format(*ids)
    for key in sorted(entries.keys()):
        cur_entries = entries[key]
        # for each id, find the entry, if not found, use placeholder '_'
        outputs = [cur_entries[_id] if _id in cur_entries else '_' for _id in ids]
        print '{:^6} {:^6} {:^6}'.format(*outputs)

entries = parse_inputs(inputs)
print_entries(entries)
```

Output is:

```
  M      L      K   
abcM1  abcL1    _   
  _    aefL2    _   
  _      _    aefK3
```

Comment: Thank you! Let me try it out for the exhaustive set of entries at my end.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to firstly sort the list based on 5th index using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function, then you will have to call the [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) based on 5th index (using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to achieve this). For example:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> my_list = ['abc**M**1', 'abc**L**1', 'aef**L**2', 'aef**K**3', 'xyz**M**3']

>>> [[i.replace('*', '') for i in j] for _, j in groupby(sorted(my_list, key=itemgetter(5)), key=itemgetter(5))]
[['aefK3'], ['abcL1', 'aefL2'], ['abcM1', 'xyzM3']]
#    ^           ^                    ^
#    K-Group     L-Group              M-Group
```

Based on the example mentioned in the question, it looks like that your list is already sorted. If that's the case, you may skip the sorting part.

Now you have basket with each group. In order to fill it with empty `-`. You may create a for loop as:

```
# same value extracted from above code
group_basket  = [['aefK3'], ['abcL1', 'aefL2'], ['abcM1', 'xyzM3']]

depth = 3

for b in group_basket:
    for i in range(depth):
        if i >= len(b) or not b[i].endswith(str(i+1)):
            b.insert(i, '-')
```

The final value hold by `group_basket` will be:

```
>>> group_basket
[['-', '-', 'aefK3'], 
 ['abcL1', 'aefL2', '-'], 
 ['abcM1', '-', 'xyzM3']]
```

You may print the data in the desired format using `zip` as:

```
for x in zip(*group_basket[::-1]):
    print('\t'.join(x))

# which prints:
# --------------------
# abcM1  abcL1    -
#  -     aefL2    -
# xyzM3   -      aefK3
```

Comment: which part represent the `-` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes I have my list sorted and as I mentioned I am already using the groupby function to sort out these lists based on the 4th character (L/M/K). But the main problem is printing these in the desired format as shown in the output above.

Comment: The '-' represents basically an empty entry in a specific row. This happens where for a given pattern (abc/aef) there is no equivalent version (M/L/K) or ID (1/2/3) available.

Comment: @Sreeder check the edited version. I think you should be able to print the data in the desired format

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, thanks for the solution, it really helps! But one thing is that in my "desired output format", each pattern is expected to have unique row for a given version and ID. But in the solution you gave has the 3rd row in such a way both xyz & aef pattern are in the same row. I would like to have each of those in separate rows as they are different patterns.

Comment: But I thought the row is based on the last digit of the string? Or is it based on the pattern at the start?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, yes the row is populated based on the following 2 rules, (i) The first rule is to take each pattern into separate rows. (ii) Once the pattern is identified, the different IDs for the same version should be in different rows.

Comment: Thanks for your code, it gave me lot of tips in learning python better. But as I requested before do you have a suggestion to make the row unique for each pattern? For eg. the third row from your output should have "xyz" entry in the next line.